# Vert.x fake/embedded mongo

Tags: mongodb, cucumber, vert.x, functional-testing, embedded-database

I have a service in which I need to implement functional tests(Cucumber) which makes some rest call.

Now earlier in my previous spring projects I had used [fongo](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo) but I guess its not working with Vert.x

Now for my cucumber tests, how do I implement the fake mongo/embedded mongo 
or is their a another library all together. I also tried [vertx-embedded-mongo-db](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-embedded-mongo-db) but there it lacks good documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and I achieved it by using `vertx-embedded-mongodb`

What I did is started `vertx-embedded-mongodb` vertical and then I started my verticle which listens to mongo port `27018`.

```
DeploymentOptions embeddedMongoOptions = new DeploymentOptions()
  .setWorker(true)
  .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("port", 27018).put("version", "3.4.3"));

vertx.rxDeployVerticle(EmbeddedMongoVerticle.class.getName(), embeddedMongoOptions)
.map(id -> {
    return new DeploymentOptions()
            .setWorker(true)
            .setConfig(myApplicationCongig);
})
.flatMap(options -> vertx.rxDeployVerticle(MyApp.class.getName(), options))
.subscribe();
```

Just make sure that your applications mongo is configured to listen 27018 instead of 27017 for test env.

Also above solution is only for Vert.x `3.x.x`. `vertx-embedded-mongodb` is no longer supported for `4.x.x`.